# Flask endpoint issue - decorator login check

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, decorator, python-decorators

I'm getting an issue

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'Welcome' instead?
```

Welcome is another function in the application (first function defined)

```
def loginRequired(func):
    def wrapper():
        access_token = session.get('access_token')
        if access_token is None:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            return func

    return wrapper
@app.route('/Homepage')
@loginRequired
def home():    
    return render_template('Homepage.html', title="Title")

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    return google.authorize(callback=callback)


@app.route(REDIRECT_URI)
@google.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    access_token = resp['access_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token, ''
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


@google.tokengetter
def get_access_token():
    return session.get('access_token')
```

Traceback message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_oauth.py", line 433, in decorated
    return f(*((data,) + args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Barry\PycharmProjects\FYP\welcome.py", line 169, in authorized
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 312, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1641, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 305, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1758, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'home'. Did you mean 'Welcome' instead?
```

Google is doing the sign in okay(being prompted), but i cant seem to be able to get the redirect working for home.
If i change home to another function (that isent login required) then the redirect works

Also if i place the lines

```
access_token = session.get('access_token')
if access_token is None:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

inside the home function and not include the decorator  it works

Thoughts?

Comment: Can u post Trace-back error message?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Traceback is here http://pastebin.com/wZS0s6Xm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution

I followed Flasks docs and found this login decorator. This worked.
it appears you Use `functools.wraps()` to handle this for you.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/

```
   from functools import wraps
    from flask import g, request, redirect, url_for

   def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        access_token = session.get('access_token')
        if access_token is None:
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```